# can anyone help me to get the error cleared?

Tags: lua, love2d

1.i,ve got error while implementing the game mario in games50 the error shows in the statemachine and its like

```
    function StateMachine:change(stateName, enterParams)
    
        assert(self.states[stateName]) -- state must exist!
        self.current:exit()
        self.current = self.states[stateName]()
        self.current:enter(enterParams)
    end
```

**Error**

```
src/StateMachine.lua:18: attempt to call method 'enter' (a nil value)
```

Traceback

```
src/StateMachine.lua:18: in function 'change'
main.lua:21: in function 'load'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

Comment: Why do you invoke in `self.states[stateName]()`?  What is "state" in your program?

Answer (score 0):

OK. So you invoke a function called "enter" which is contained in a table called "current", which is contained in another table passed in the hidden parameter "self" of the function "change".

You need first to check how the "change" function is called.

Check if it's something like:

```
xxxx:change(...
```

and not:

```
xxx.change(...
```

Because in the second version, the hidden "self" parameter (which will contain a reference to "xxx") is not provided.

Then, check is "self.current" is valid, right after `self.current = self.states[stateName]()` by printing it:

```
print(self.current)
```

If you see a table reference in your console, it's good.

At this stage, it will show you that the problem is the "enter" function which does not exists in the table returned by `self.current = self.states[stateName]()`.

All your code sounds like you're using an external library from which you do not master the use. I advice you to start coding game with your own code, simple games, not using external code.